# ORA-01722 INVALID NUMBER in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting invalid number error message while executing the below select statement.Can any one have an idea about the issue..Please let me know.

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('2015/01/22 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

actually i want oracle standard date format without time stamp for this date '2015/01/22 00:00:00'

Comment: Your sample query doesn't make much sense.  Can you show us your actual production query?

Comment: The first parameter for `TO_CHAR` should be a non-character datatype - e.g. a date or a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
select to_date('2015/01/22 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt
from dual
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a3a6/1/0

As an FYI, the Oracle `DATE` data type does include the time component (just not down to fractional seconds, as is the case with the `TIMESTAMP` data type).

If you are converting values and want to bring all the time values to zero you can use the `trunc` function like this (which changes 12:07:00 to 00:00:00):

```
select trunc(to_date('2015/01/22 12:07:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD') as dt_with_time_zerod
from dual
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a3a6/2/0

If the source is itself a date and you want to convert the date to a string in the Oracle default date format ('DD-MON-RR') you can achieve that by running:

```
select to_char(trunc(to_date('2015/01/22 12:07:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD'),'DD-MON-RR') as dt_with_time_zerod
from dual
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a3a6/3/0

Answer (score 0):

If it's a date field, to_char without a mask will give you what you say you want.

Comment: Only if `TO_CHAR()` recognizes it as a date.

Comment: How could to_char not recognize a date field as a date?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a date field. If you mean a value stored in a `DATE` column, then yes, `TO_CHAR ()` will recognize it as a date. If you mean a string literal containing a date, then `TO_CHAR()` *may* recognize it based on the NLS settings in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

> actually i want oracle standard date format without time stamp for this date '2015/01/22 00:00:00'

I'm not sure what you mean by "Oracle standard date format." The format in which a date would appear would be based on your NLS settings (in particular, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`). If you are just trying to format this string representing a date, then you might want something like the following:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2015/01/22 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
  FROM dual;
```

That is, you have the `TO_CHAR()` and `TO_DATE()` functions in the wrong order, and an incomplete date mask for the call to `TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using date literals with the standard [ISO 8601 format](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

```
date '2015-01-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to give hour-minute-second if you do not want to show the time.

This is my simplest answer :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015/01/22','YYYY/MM/DD') FROM dual
```

[image: Query Result]